# Passing function as a parameter into another function error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a 'navigateTo is not defined' error in my JS with the following. I'm pretty sure I have passed the function `navigateTo` as a parameter to the `openCart()` function so unsure where I'm going wrong?

```
$(function() {
    var form = $('form#checkout-form'),
    $sections = $('[data-step]');

    function navigateTo(index) {
        $sections.removeClass('is--active').eq(index).addClass('is--active');
    }
});

$(document).on('click', 'nav.main a.cart', function(e) {
    openCart();
});
function openCart(navigateTo) {
    navigateTo(1);
    disableScroll = false;
}
```

Comment: navigateTo is not in the scope. Put this function in a higher scope to call from other function

Comment: It's pretty simple thing. It all relates to the `scope`. `navigateTo()` is not defined in the scope of `openCart()` even though you call the `openCart()` in the `DOM` ready function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function `openCart` should go to inside the dom ready function otherwise it doesn't call the function and another thing you need to pass the callback as parameter `navigateTo` into the `opencart` function   like `openCart(navigateTo)`;

```js
$(function() {
    var form = $('form#checkout-form'),
    $sections = $('[data-step]');

    function navigateTo(index) {
    alert(2);
        $sections.removeClass('is--active').eq(index).addClass('is--active');
    }
    $(document).on('click', 'div', function(e) {
        openCart(navigateTo);
    });
    function openCart(navigateTo) {
        navigateTo(1);
        disableScroll = false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hahah</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a scope issue. Wrap your whole script in a closure and you'll be fine;

```
(function($) {
    // your script here
})(jQuery)
```

But get rid of the `$(function() { }` around the first block as well.